# How to save url that a user clicks on (PHP)

Tags: php, html, url, click

I have a code where people need to input an address and then it opens below. And I also insert the url into the databse to keep track of the visited websites (like a browsing history).

```
<?php
if($_POST){
$add=$_POST['url'];
}
?>

<...>

if (isset($_POST['history'])) {
$url = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['url']);
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
$query = "INSERT INTO websites (url, username, date) 
          VALUES('$url', '$username','$date')";
mysqli_query($db, $query);

  <...>
<input type="url" name="url">
<button type="submit" class="btn" name="history">Open</button>
  <...>
<iframe src="<?php echo $add; ?>" id="frame" height="800px" width="1100px" />
```

The problem is that I also need to save the websites that users enter when they click the links inside other websites. How would I save their urls into my database?

Answer (score 0):

This should not be possible, because  does only link to the given website. All clicks should be processed in the inserted html-document, (often antother server) (see https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html#h-16.5).

It should be possible with cURL. There you can include html documents. You also can process GET and POST statements. From the curl manual:

DOWNLOAD TO A FILE:
Get a web page and store in a local file with a specific name:

```
    curl -o thatpage.html http://www.netscape.com/
```

You can do nearly everything with cURL. You find the manual at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html